Positional Audio not working with WebRTC streams
So I had defined a Component Sound which creates a mesh on top of every other player in a room, and having spatial audio with mesh as source and camera as listener, and it worked well.
import { useEffect, useRef, } from 'react'
import { useThree, useLoader, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import * as THREE from 'three'

interface SoundProps {
  url: string
  is_Playing: boolean
}

export default function Sound({ url, is_Playing = true }: SoundProps) {
  const { camera, } = useThree()
  const soundRef = useRef<THREE.PositionalAudio | null>(null)
  const listenerRef = useRef(new THREE.AudioListener())
  const buffer = useLoader(THREE.AudioLoader, url)
  const meshRef = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    camera.add(listenerRef.current)
    return () => {
      camera.remove(listenerRef.current)
    }
  }, [camera])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (buffer && meshRef.current) {
      const sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio(listenerRef.current)
      sound.setBuffer(buffer)
      sound.setRefDistance(10)
      sound.setLoop(true)
      meshRef.current.add(sound)
      soundRef.current = sound

      if (is_Playing) {
        sound.play()
      } else {
        sound.pause()
      }

      return () => {
        if (sound.isPlaying) {
          sound.stop()
        }
        sound.disconnect()
        if (meshRef.current) {
          meshRef.current.remove(sound)
        }
      }
    }
  }, [buffer, is_Playing])

  return (
    <mesh ref={meshRef} position={[0, 3, 0]}>
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color='red' />
      <positionalAudio ref={soundRef} args={[listenerRef.current]} />
    </mesh>
  )
}


Now I am trying to make a similar Component PeerSound which receives WebRTC MediaStream as a prop and play positional audio, but the audio's volume is not changing at all on moving the player from the camera (no Positional Audio), what am I doing wrong here?
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import * as THREE from 'three'

interface SoundProps {
  stream: MediaStream | null
  is_Playing: boolean
}

export default function PeerSound({ stream, is_Playing = false }: SoundProps) {
  const { camera, scene } = useThree()
  const soundRef = useRef<THREE.PositionalAudio | null>(null)
  const audioListenerRef = useRef(new THREE.AudioListener())
  const audioContextRef = useRef<AudioContext | null>(null)
  const meshRef = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    camera.add(audioListenerRef.current)

    return () => {
      camera.remove(audioListenerRef.current)
    }
  }, [camera])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stream && meshRef.current) {
      if (!audioContextRef.current) {
        audioContextRef.current = new AudioContext()
        console.log('Context', audioContextRef.current.state)
      }
      const audio = new Audio()
      audio.srcObject = stream
      audio.muted = false

      const sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio(audioListenerRef.current)
      sound.setMediaStreamSource(audio.srcObject as MediaStream)
      sound.setRefDistance(1)
      sound.setMaxDistance(5)
      sound.setRolloffFactor(2)

      meshRef.current.add(sound)
      soundRef.current = sound

      audio.onloadedmetadata = () => {
        audio.play()
      }

      return () => {
        sound.disconnect()
        meshRef.current?.remove(sound)
      }
    }
  }, [stream, scene])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (soundRef.current) {
      soundRef.current.setVolume(is_Playing ? 1 : 0)
    }
  }, [is_Playing])

  return (
    <mesh ref={meshRef} castShadow position={[0, 3, 0]} scale={2}>
      <icosahedronGeometry args={[0.3, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial
        flatShading
        color='mediumpurple'
        transparent={true}
      />
      <positionalAudio ref={soundRef} args={[audioListenerRef.current]} />
    </mesh>
  )
}



I think it should work if you remove audio.play(). The Web Audio API is probably rendering positional audio but it's hard to hear if the audio element is playing regular audio at the same time, too.
